# I can't show a form that isn't top level with form.ShowDialog()

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My startup form is a modal security form which works fine. But, if the user "logs out", the security form must be displayed again as a modal dialog. This last step is where everything goes wrong. It shows the form, in front of my other forms, but it's not modal...

First, I call a method that's written in a module, because I have to be able to call this method from every form I want.

```
Public Sub CallWaiterKey()
Dim oForm As frmWaiterKey = New frmWaiterKey()
    Try
        If mWaiterKey.Length > 0 And mWaiterKeyType.Length > 0 Then

            If Convert.ToInt32(mWaiterKey) > 0 And Convert.ToInt32(mWaiterKeyType) = 2 Then
                oForm.TypeOfKey = 2
            ElseIf Convert.ToInt32(mWaiterKey) > 0 And Convert.ToInt32(mWaiterKeyType) = 1 Then
                oForm.TypeOfKey = 1
            End If
            'here it goes wrong
            oForm.ShowDialog()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I call `oForm.ShowDialog()` (that's the `frmWaiterKey`), it comes up but isn't modal.
I can still click the buttons that are placed on `frmMenu`, the form from which I called `CallWaiterKey()`.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Or should I make the call in an other way?

Comment: You may want to reexamine your method of creating a new dialog each time. When a Form displayed using ShowDialog is closed, ["...the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

Comment: I can imagine a scenario where, after a day without a reboot and many, many bartenders logging in and out, your system performance could be negatively impacted by all of the hidden forms running in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My VB sucks so ignore syntax errors)

To achieve what you are asking, specify the hosting form.

```
Public Sub CallWaiterKey(ownerForm as Form)
  Dim oForm As frmWaiterKey = New frmWaiterKey()
     ' .... 
            'here it goes wrong
            oForm.ShowDialog(ownerForm)
     ' ....
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. Now I still have some threading problems but I hope I'll fix them. Thank you!

Comment: According to the documentation, when a owner is not specified ["the currently active window is made the owner of the dialog box"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

Comment: @Cyborgx37 -- Yes, that's true. I figured out that on the moment of my call, no form was really 'active'. Everything works now using the code from above. The threading problems are also fixed. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use ShowDialog; but I **believe** that you need to specify the window owner to enforce the modality.  If I'm wrong here, others will correct me.

```
oForm.ShowDialog(me)
```

** HOLD ON ** I will alter this in a second, I just recalled that you're calling from a module, **me** doesn't evaluate in a basic module.

Here is a [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works when I give the userForm as parameter with oForm.ShowDialog().

Comment: Yep, that is it.  If I answered your question please mark this as such.